# Quoting a sentence containing a quote: Which quotation mark should I use?

Tags: american-english, quotation-marks, quotations

In American English, the quotation mark normally used is the double quotation mark.

> Edema asked, "Am I an alliteration addict?"

When quoting text, which quotation marks should I use?

- Single quotation mark for the external one, and double quotation mark for the other one

  > Edemo said, 'Edema asked, "Am I an alliteration addict?"'
- Double quotation mark for the external one, and single quotation mark for the other one

  > Edemo said, "Edema asked, 'Am I an alliteration addict?'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The US "standard" is to start with doubles outside and alternate with singles as you work inward. The British 'standard' is just the opposite.

But any given publisher or style manual may depart from the local standard.

My advice is that you do it whichever way you like, as long as you're consistent, and then forget about it. Let your publisher worry about it; if he cares, he can have his copyeditors run a macro to change it. They gotta be paid for something!